# Rails internationalisation help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have downloaded the danish locale (da.yml) and put it in config/locales

I get this error: couldn't parse YAML at line 20 column 14

It is the same error as I get in in simple form for [Rails 3 simple form error : couldn't parse YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246351/rails-3-simple-form-error-couldnt-parse-yaml)

My application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :da

    # JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
    # config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
  end
end
```

My view file:

```
<% @konkurrancer.each do |vind| %>
   <tr onclick="window.open('<%= vind.tracking %>')" 
      <td><%= vind.udtraekkes.strftime("%d %B") %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
```

Error when :

```
C:\Rails\app>rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> I18n.l Time.now, :format => :short
Psych::SyntaxError: couldn't parse YAML at line 0 column 0
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse_stream'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:205:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib/i18n/backend/bas
e.rb:170:in `load_yml'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib/i18n/backend/bas
e.rb:156:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib/i18n/backend/bas
e.rb:15:in `block in load_translations'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib/i18n/backend/bas
e.rb:15:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib/i18n/backend/bas
e.rb:15:in `load_translations'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib/i18n/backend/sim
ple.rb:55:in `init_translations'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib/i18n/backend/sim
ple.rb:69:in `lookup'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib/i18n/backend/bas
e.rb:26:in `translate'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib/i18n.rb:155:in `
translate'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib/i18n/backend/bas
e.rb:55:in `localize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib/i18n.rb:235:in `
localize'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'irb(main):002:0>
```

But my dates names in view does not change. 
My danish locale file http://pastie.org/1651134

Comment: Could you post your view please?

Comment: Have you restarted the server? You need to do that whenever adding a new locale file.

Comment: Yes I have restarted the server

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `l` translation helper for dates and not use strftime (see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats)).

So if you had this in your locale:

```
da:
  time:
    formats:
      short: "arrrround %H"
```

Then in your view, you'd use:

```
<%= l vind.udtraekkes, :format => :short %>
```

Comment: I get a syntax error: @output_buffer.append= ( 1 vind.udtraekkes, :format => :shor...

Comment: Hmmm. Are you using '1' instead of 'l' in your view, or is that just what's coming out in the error? Can you add the time formats part of the locale file to your question, and update the view code to reflect the use of the `l` I18n helper?

Comment: Yes I did. Now I get following error: couldn't parse YAML at line 0 column 0

Comment: Also, can you translate from the console? `I18n.l Time.now, :format => :short` (substituting `:short` for one of the formats defined in your locale)

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong with your locale file. Maybe try checking it on [yamllint.com](http://yamllint.com/), or slap it in a [pastie](http://pastie.org/) and add it to your question, if it's not sensitive.

Comment: Line 180; you've got a stray letter 's' which is making it invalid.

Comment: I have removed the s in the locale but I get this error: couldn't parse YAML at line 20 column 14 in view

Comment: Not sure what's causing that. It passes the lint test when the s is removed.

Comment: I get the same error in new http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246351/rails-3-simple-form-error-couldnt-parse-yaml