# Rails 3 simple form error : couldn't parse YAML 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My new.html.erb:

```
  <h1>New konkurrancer</h1>

    <%= simple_form_for [:admin, @konkurrancer] do |f| %
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>


    <%= link_to 'Back', admin_konkurrancers_path %>
```

And I get this error in view(http://localhost:3000/admin/konkurrancers/new):

```
Psych::SyntaxError in Admin/konkurrancers#new

Showing C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/admin/konkurrancers/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

couldn't parse YAML at line 20 column 14

Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <h1>New konkurrancer</h1>
2: 
3: <%= simple_form_for [:admin, @konkurrancer] do |f| %>
4:  <%= f.input :name %>
5:  <%= f.button :submit %>
6: <% end %>
```

See full trace here http://pastie.org/1652928

My controller:

```
    class Admin::KonkurrancersController < Admin::AdminController
      # GET /konkurrancers
      # GET /konkurrancers.xml
      def index
        @konkurrancers = Konkurrancer.all
        @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(:all)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @konkurrancers }
        end
      end
      # GET /konkurrancers/1
      # GET /konkurrancers/1.xml
      def show
        @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @konkurrancer }
        end
      end

      # GET /konkurrancers/new
      # GET /konkurrancers/new.xml
      def new
        @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.new
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @konkurrancer }
        end
      end
    def statistik

    @reklamers = Reklamer.find(:all)

    end
      # GET /konkurrancers/1/edit
      def edit
        @konkurrance = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])
      end

      # POST /konkurrancers
      # POST /konkurrancers.xml
      def create
        @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.new(params[:konkurrancer])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @konkurrancer.save
            format.html { redirect_to(@konkurrancer, :notice => 'Konkurrancer was successfully created.') }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @konkurrancer, :status => :created, :location => @konkurrancer }
          else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @konkurrancer.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PUT /konkurrancers/1
      # PUT /konkurrancers/1.xml
      def update
        @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @konkurrancer.update_attributes(params[:konkurrancer])
            format.html { redirect_to(@konkurrancer, :notice => 'Konkurrancer was successfully updated.') }
            format.xml  { head :ok }
          else
            format.html { render :action => "edit" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @konkurrancer.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /konkurrancers/1
      # DELETE /konkurrancers/1.xml
      def destroy
        @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])
        @konkurrancer.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to(admin_konkurrancers_path) }
          format.xml  { head :ok }
      end
      end
      end

In view I get following error: 

    NoMethodError in Admin/konkurrancers#new

    Showing C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/admin/konkurrancers/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

    undefined method `konkurrancers_path' for #<#<Class:0x3e1ae48>:0x3e16270>

    Extracted source (around line #3):

    1: <h1>New konkurrancer</h1>
    2: 
    3: <%= simple_form_for(@konkurrancer) do |f| %>
    4: 
    5:  <%= f.input :name %>
    6:  <%= f.button :submit %>

    Rails.root: C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen
```

Rake routes:

```
C:\Rails\konkurranceportalen>rake routes
(in C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen)
        admin_kategoris GET    /admin/kategoris(.:format)              {:action=
>"index", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
                        POST   /admin/kategoris(.:format)              {:action=
>"create", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
     new_admin_kategori GET    /admin/kategoris/new(.:format)          {:action=
>"new", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
    edit_admin_kategori GET    /admin/kategoris/:id/edit(.:format)     {:action=
>"edit", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
         admin_kategori GET    /admin/kategoris/:id(.:format)          {:action=
>"show", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
                        PUT    /admin/kategoris/:id(.:format)          {:action=
>"update", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
                        DELETE /admin/kategoris/:id(.:format)          {:action=
>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
    admin_konkurrancers GET    /admin/konkurrancers(.:format)          {:action=
>"index", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
                        POST   /admin/konkurrancers(.:format)          {:action=
>"create", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
 new_admin_konkurrancer GET    /admin/konkurrancers/new(.:format)      {:action=
>"new", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
edit_admin_konkurrancer GET    /admin/konkurrancers/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=
>"edit", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
     admin_konkurrancer GET    /admin/konkurrancers/:id(.:format)      {:action=
>"show", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
                        PUT    /admin/konkurrancers/:id(.:format)      {:action=
>"update", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
                        DELETE /admin/konkurrancers/:id(.:format)      {:action=
>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
        admin_reklamers GET    /admin/reklamers(.:format)              {:action=
>"index", :controller=>"admin/reklamers"}
                        POST   /admin/reklamers(.:format)              {:action=
>"create", :controller=>"admin/reklamers"}
     new_admin_reklamer GET    /admin/reklamers/new(.:format)          {:action=
>"new", :controller=>"admin/reklamers"}
    edit_admin_reklamer GET    /admin/reklamers/:id/edit(.:format)     {:action=
>"edit", :controller=>"admin/reklamers"}
         admin_reklamer GET    /admin/reklamers/:id(.:format)          {:action=
>"show", :controller=>"admin/reklamers"}
                        PUT    /admin/reklamers/:id(.:format)          {:action=
>"update", :controller=>"admin/reklamers"}
                        DELETE /admin/reklamers/:id(.:format)          {:action=
>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/reklamers"}
              reklamers GET    /reklamers(.:format)                    {:action=
>"index", :controller=>"reklamers"}
                        POST   /reklamers(.:format)                    {:action=
>"create", :controller=>"reklamers"}
           new_reklamer GET    /reklamers/new(.:format)                {:action=
>"new", :controller=>"reklamers"}
          edit_reklamer GET    /reklamers/:id/edit(.:format)           {:action=
>"edit", :controller=>"reklamers"}
               reklamer GET    /reklamers/:id(.:format)                {:action=
>"show", :controller=>"reklamers"}
                        PUT    /reklamers/:id(.:format)                {:action=
>"update", :controller=>"reklamers"}
                        DELETE /reklamers/:id(.:format)                {:action=
>"destroy", :controller=>"reklamers"}
     konkurrencer_index GET    /konkurrencer(.:format)                 {:action=
>"index", :controller=>"konkurrancers"}
                        POST   /konkurrencer(.:format)                 {:action=
>"create", :controller=>"konkurrancers"}
       new_konkurrencer GET    /konkurrencer/new(.:format)             {:action=
>"new", :controller=>"konkurrancers"}
      edit_konkurrencer GET    /konkurrencer/:id/edit(.:format)        {:action=
>"edit", :controller=>"konkurrancers"}
           konkurrencer GET    /konkurrencer/:id(.:format)             {:action=
>"show", :controller=>"konkurrancers"}
                        PUT    /konkurrencer/:id(.:format)             {:action=
>"update", :controller=>"konkurrancers"}
                        DELETE /konkurrencer/:id(.:format)             {:action=
>"destroy", :controller=>"konkurrancers"}
                  admin        /admin(.:format)                        {:control
ler=>"admin", :action=>"index"}
              statistik        /statistik(.:format)                    {:control
ler=>"public", :action=>"statistik"}
                               /:id(.:format)                          {:control
ler=>"kategoris", :action=>"show"}
                   root        /(.:format)                             {:control
ler=>"public", :action=>"index"}

C:\Rails\konkurranceportalen>
```

My route file:

```
Konkurranceportalen::Application.routes.draw do
namespace :admin do
resources :kategoris
resources :konkurrancers
resources :reklamers
   end
resources :reklamers
resources :konkurrencer, :controller => 'konkurrancers'
match "/admin" => "admin#index"
match "/statistik" => "public#statistik"
match '/:id' => 'kategoris#show'
root :to => "public#index"
end
```

Comment: can you run `rake routes` and paste the output here? I reckon that the problem is that ruby is assuming that the plural of konkurrancer is something different from konkurrancers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<%= simple_form_for ['admin', @konkurrancer] do |f| %>
```

It looks like you're in a name spaced model?

Comment: Yes I have a name spaced model. I get following error couldn't parse YAML at line 20 column 14

Extracted source (around line #5):

Comment: we'll need to see the yml file that the problem is being reported in

Comment: Do you mean the language locale file?

Comment: depends if that is where the next error is, show the full error dump if you can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You're using a namespaced model - you must reference the namespace in your form path.

Try this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @konkurrancer] do |f| %>
```