# Rails 3 / Ruby error in view : couldn't parse YAML at line 20 column 14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error in view: couldn't parse YAML at line 20 column 14

Here:
[Rails internationalisation help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244272/rails-internationalisation-help)

And here:
[Rails 3 simple form error : couldn't parse YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246351/rails-3-simple-form-error-couldnt-parse-yaml)

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely did not end put a whitespace at the end of your YAML file.

Comment: I have put some white space at the end of the locale yaml file. But I still get the error

Comment: I previously had this problem and it was in my __config/database.yml__ file.

Comment: I did delete my danish locale and did add space in the english locale file and database.yml

Answer (score 1):

Putting the Quotes fixed my error:
couldn't parse yaml at line 18

Answer (score 0):

Put the password in `config/database.yml` into quotes

```
username: dbadmin  
password: "?!?!?pass?!?!?word?!?!"
```